# fill json array with rankings list

Tags: php, sql, json

I'm trying to fill a json array from a selected table of my database.
The main table contains all information of users, that I want to select 10 members with top XP out of it.

My code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "MyServerName";
$dbUsername = "DatabaseUsername";
$dbPassword = "DatabasePassword";
$dbName = "DatabaseID";
$tableName = "TableName";

$conn = new mysqli($serverName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
try{
    if(isset($_POST['USERNAME'])){
        $userName = $_POST['USERNAME'];
        $sqlTopMembers = "SELECT XP, username FROM $tableName LIMIT 10 ORDER BY XP DESC ";
        if (!($result = $conn->query($sqlTopMembers)))
            die($conn->error);
        if ($result->num_rows) {
            $i = 0;
            $rankings = null;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $rankings[$i] = $row;
                $i++;
            }
            echo json_encode(array($tableName => $rankings));
    }
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo "Error ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? The text looks like chopped off.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no reason to check if a `USERNAME` was posted, as you never use the `USERNAME`-field. Second, you missed an closing curly.

At least, you should reorder your sql statement - `LIMIT` is used AFTER `ORDER BY`

```
$serverName = "MyServerName";
$dbUsername = "DatabaseUsername";
$dbPassword = "DatabasePassword";
$dbName = "DatabaseID";
$tableName = "TableName";

$conn = new mysqli($serverName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
try {
    $sqlTopMembers = "SELECT XP, username FROM $tableName ORDER BY XP DESC LIMIT 10";
    if (!($result = $conn->query($sql)))
        die($conn->error);
    if ($result->num_rows) {
        $rankings = [];
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rankings[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode(array($tableName => $rankings));
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rankings[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode(array($tableName => $rankings));
```

into this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $rankings[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($rankings);
```